# how to enable Http request on Apache server?

Tags: apache-http-server

i want to enable http request on my apache server so i can upload any file to that server with `curl -T /path/to/file [server_address/]` i tried googling it but the answers were for old version of Apache2, and i'm getting this error if i do that without enabling or something

```
hamker@hamkerz ~ % curl -T hacc.sh http://3x.142.1xx.81/     
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
<p>The requested method PUT is not allowed for this URL.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server at 34.125.172.81 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Limit](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limit) and [LimitExcept](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#limitexcept) directives to remove the `405 Method Not Allowed` error you are receiving. An example from this [Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54942832/how-to-allow-put-method-in-apache2) for all five of the standard HTTP methods:

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST PUT DELETE OPTIONS>
    # Apache 2.4 
    Require all granted
</Limit>
```

Both of the directives above can appear in `<Directory>` blocks or `.htaccess` files.

With that said, as far as I am aware, I do not believe simply enabling `PUT` will allow you to upload files. As (subtly) indicated in the Stack Overflow question above with the directive `Dav On`, you likely need [mod_dav](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html) and its related modules `mod_dav_fs` and `mod_dav_lock` (which allow [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) access) enabled and configured correctly to actually upload files (assuming you aren't using `PUT` in conjunction with e.g. a PHP script). Beyond the example offered in the official Apache documentation, [here is an (outdated but hopefully still useful) Digital Ocean tutorial on setting up WebDAV with Apache on Ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-webdav-access-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04).

Comment: yeah i got it but is there anything simple which i can use to allow any file upload via curl on my server without any restrictions?

Comment: *"Is there anything simple which I can use to allow any file upload via `curl` on my server without any restrictions?"* - via Apache, WebDAV is likely your "best" option. Security issues aside, you can, of course, also simply install an FTP server and give it access to the whole server as well.